Understanding the Meaning and Function of P(x|z) in Variational Autoencoder
I have a question regarding the functioning of Variational Autoencoders (VAEs), specifically about the meaning of P(x∣z). There seem to be a few possibilities for its interpretation:

When z is fixed at a specific value, the probability that the decoder's output belongs to the distribution of the input dataset (e.g., MNIST).

The probability that an input sample x belongs to the distribution of the results obtained by sampling z from the prior distribution many times and passing them through the decoder.

z is given as a specific sampled value, and the decoder explicitly outputs μ and σ, with the probability that the input sample x belongs to this distribution.


Could someone clarify which of these interpretations is correct, or what the precise meaning is?
